# How to avoid timeout error on jsonp request?

Tags: http, angular, jsonp, rxjs, observable

How to handle timeout of the jsonp request? I have a 10s timeout on the observable returned by jsonp.get() method but the request remains in browser even though timeout has reached. After 1-2 minute timeout I receive this error in console:

> GET
>   [https://myserver/?url=asdf&callback=**ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished](https://myserver/?url=asdf&callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished)
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
>   browser_jsonp.js:64

In my component want to make a jsonp request and subscribe to it like this:

```
this.service.jsonp(url).subscribe(
    (response) => { this.handleResponse(response); },
    (err) => { this.handleError(err); }
  );
```

This is the jsonp method in my service:

```
jsonp(url: string): Observable<any> {
  let params = new URLSearchParams();

  params.set('url', url);
  params.set('callback', 'JSONP_CALLBACK');

  return this.jsonp.get('https://myserver', {search: params})
    .timeout(10000)
    .catch((err: Response) => Observable.throw(err))
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSONP` is actually adding `<script>` tag to the page. Angular just removes node from document (this is ok for IE and Edge, but in Firefox you will have to use `document.onbeforescriptexecute`, don't know how Chrome handles this), but script is still loading and eventually it dies with browser timeout and logs to console.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So basically, are you saying that I can not catch errors caused by jsonp requests and hence nor by script tags?

Comment: Why do you need to catch it? Chrome just prints resource loading errors to console for your convenience.